# Laravel restore in cpanel login issue

Tags: laravel

What I did:

1) Restored my cpanel account backup which is basically my laravel app. Laravel login worked fine before restore.

2) I tried to login to the laravel app and got the error "Access denied for user".

3) Cleared my cache. No luck still access denied.

4) Checked .env variables still the same. Tested logging into db from cmd prompt with same .env parameters, all good.

5) Next tested .env file by changing username variable, for example before it was username bob123 and I changed it to bob12 .

6) Next I deleted config.php in bootstrap/cache. Ran php artisan config:cache. This created a new config.php file in the cache folder. I saw the changes I made in the new config.php file. So I saw bob12.

7) Now I checked the .env variables on my access denied error page in the browser. The variables dont match the changes I made to the username. It is still the original username, bob123. Also on the browser error page the APP-URL is missing the ssl reference. It is http instead of the https that is in the config.php file and my .env file. I did restore the cpanel and https was absent for a short period of time but ssl is working now.

Comment: use tinker and check whether your DB connection is correct or not. `php artisan tinker` and then use `config('database')` it'll show the correct configuration.

Comment: Command "tinker" is not defined.